# Hide Displayed Class and Show the Clicked One in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 menu button and each has submenu. The submenus are hidden by default. When any of the menu is clicked, the submenu under it displays. This is working but if I click on the second or third button it displays its submenu and the submenu of the first one will still be showing. I want any displayed button to hide whenever any other one is clicked.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class='mainMenu'>
<button class='menus'> aTone </button>
    <div class='sub'>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button class='menus'> A1 </button>
                    <button class='menus'> B2 </button>
                    <button class='menus'> B3 </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button class='menus'> bTone </button>
    <div class='sub'>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button class='menus'> B1 </button>
                    <button class='menus'> B2 </button>
                    <button class='menus'> B3 </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button class='menus'> ATone </button>
    <div class='sub'>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button class='menus'> C1 </button>
                    <button class='menus'> C2 </button>
                    <button class='menus'> C3 </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('.sub').hide();
$(document).on('click', '.menus', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next('.sub').slideToggle(400);
});
```

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have your submenus inside `.mainMenu` div. Replaced `$(document)` with `$('.mainMenu')`. Because you're delegating events on children of the document object, so events bubble up to the document level. It's more convenient to select the closest parent `$('.mainMenu')` you have (and the parent must exist on the page at load). Try this:

```
$('.sub').hide();
$('.mainMenu').on('click', '.menus', function(){
    $('.sub').hide(); // this will hide all submenu's
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next('.sub').slideToggle(400); // this will show submenu next to clicked button
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/6wAcM/1/)**

Comment: Have actually tried this before asking. It's working but is this best way to do this?

Comment: @Yax: Yes.As I mentioned if you have parent must on the page at load. Its best way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.menus', function(){
var $this = $(this);
$('.sub').hide();
$this.next('.sub').slideToggle(400);
});
```